# How to refactor String id to class Id in a big legacy project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring

In this big legacy project there is a core class MyObject that has an ID property, which has been coded as a String. This ID is accessed everywhere across the project.

```
public class MyObject {
  private String id;

  public String getId(){
    return id;
  }
}
```

I am looking at the possibility of refactoring this String property to a type class Id with the following methods:

```
class Id implements Comparable<Id> {
  String value
  Id(String value)
  String getValue()
  int hashCode()
  boolean equals(Object obj)
  int compareTo(Id o)
  String toString()
}
```

When refactoring, I need to keep in mind that while I can refactor our own project in any way, there are customers who use the project's API and the changes should preferably be backwards compatible. The current usages of the String IDs internally are:

- Get an object ID, store it in a variable and do some comparisons on it later
- Create a list or set and add object IDs to it or check if ID is contained already (without custom comparators)
- Compare an object ID to a String value (e.g. user input) sometimes with `equals()` and sometimes with `equalsIgnoreCase()`
- Compare two object IDs

Specifically, what I would like to do is:

- Refactor type of ID from `String` to `Id`
- Refactor the current method `String getId()` to `Id getUniqueID()`
- Where ID is compared to a string directly using `id.equals("String")` or `id.equalsIgnoreCase("String")`, change it to `id.equals(new Id("String"))`
- Add a new method (with the old name) `String getId()` that will return `getUniqueID().getValue()`. This is for backwards compatibility with customer code that relies on the old String IDs.

Of course, I could just list all usages of the property, its getters and setters, and go and replace them by hand. Sometimes, I'd probably be able to get away with using a regex, but it probably isn't that great of an idea. Besides, its plain daunting, as there are 500+ usages to edit across a couple of dozen classes, including sub-classes.

I have looked at IDEA's refactor: type migrate function, but it does not seem to be able to do it. I don't normally work in IDEA, so I might be doing something wrong, but it tells me that there are a few hundred conflicts and the list of things it can't convert is rather long.

It does not look like I can provide a mapping of the old getter `getId()` to new `getUniqueID().getValue()`, e.g.

```
myObject.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("test")
```

would need to map to

```
myObject.getUniqueID().getValue().equals(new Id("test"))
```

I imagine that this sort of refactoring should be rather popular, but so far it looks like I will have to do it mostly by hand and search+replace.

Is there an automated way of doing it? Perhaps, some refactoring tool that would allow to specify how old usage pattern would map into new usage pattern?

Comment: Is changing `getId()` to return `getValue()` an option ?

Comment: When you expose the value, there is no use in the refactoring as you don't actually encapsulate anything. Thus: avoid `getId().getValue().equals("test")` - instead work with the id only, and go for `getId().equals(IdClass.of("test"))` or something like that.

Comment: @mtj Thanks, I have modified the question to reflect that third party users already use the API and I'd prefer it to stay backwards compatible. However, this does not impact the difficulty of refactoring in any way.

Comment: @c0der I think this is a good idea for backwards compatibility, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the general answer to the posed question is indeed to use IntelliJ IDEA's functionality: Refactor → Type migration.

The challenge is that it will probably migrate a lot of other variables to the new type, and not just the variable I want to migrate.

For example, we have another class NameDescription that takes two String parameters for name and description and is sometimes used as `new NameDescription(myObject.getId(), "Some description")`. In this case, IDEA figures that it probably needs to change `NameDescription.name` from String to Id too, which is actually wrong.
In order to avoid this, one needs to preview usages after requesting type migration and manually exclude this and other cases that should not be migrated.

Furthermore, another feature of IDEA can be used to modify patterns in the code: Search/Replace Structurally that allows to define a search pattern with variables and is a bit easier to use than writing a lot of regular expressions yourself.

For backward compatibility, as @c0der suggests, the old getter would return `newIdObject.getValue()`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, for backwards compatibility, which does not require major refactoring :

```
@Deprecated
String getId() {  return getUniqueID().getValue(); }

ID getUniqueID() {
    //TODO
}
```

Manually edit `getId().getValue().equals("test")` occurrences only where it is essential and has clear benefit.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify precisely what the constraints are and what I'm trying to do. Thanks